# Javascript changing URL does not work

Tags: javascript

```
   <div class="Session:">
    <h2>Session:<a href="" onClick=switchURL('1')>1</a>&nbsp;<a href="" onClick=switchURL('2')>2</a></h2>
</div>

<script>

    function switchURL(option) {
        if (option == '1')
            document.links[0].href = 'http://localhost:123/havengit/java/javaSession1.html'     //change the url destination
        if (option == '2')
            document.links[0].href = 'http://localhost:123/havengit/java/javaSession2.html'
    }
</script>
```

Clicking on "1" link takes me to page javaSession1.html
Clicking on "2" link does not take me to page javaSession2.html. It stays on java.html page.

Comment: Should be links[1] on option 2.

Comment: `document.links`, really? You should either pass the anchor element as parameter to `switchURL`, or you should just assign to `window.location`. Or even better, don't use javascript at all and just put those links in the `href` attributes of those links!